# Is atomicity and immutability two distinct ways of solving the same problems in concurrent/parallel programming?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, immutability, atomic

Is it correct to say that one can choose to design a concurrent/parallel system using atomic operations OR using immutable types?  I.e. atomic operations leads to a designing a system of atomically shared state while immutable types leads to designing a system that avoids sharing all-together?  Are these two designs essentially substitutes for each other (solving the same underlying problem) or do they address different problems (meaning it might be possible to have to use both atomic operations and immutable types to design a fully concurrency-safe system)?

Answer (score 1):

While both concepts are relevant for concurrent systems, and both guarantee no intermediate state is ever read, they're very different and fit different scenarios. For example, iterating an immutable data structure guarantees correct and "safe" iteration, while mutable data structures are not safe for iteration even if mutating operations are atomic. On the other hand, atomically mutating a shared/central data store guarantees no incorrect data is ever read, while immutability is irrelevant since the store *has* to change.

Comment: Certainly `ConcurrentHashMap` is both mutable and iterable so i'd say that _some_ data structures and not safe for that.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it correct to say that one can choose to design a concurrent/parallel system using atomic operations OR using immutable types?

This seems somewhat like a forced argument to me.  In the example you give, it seems like these two concepts are related but only tenuously.  I'd say that these two different concepts both assist in implementing and optimizing concurrent/parallel architectures.

> Are these two designs essentially substitutes for each other (solving the same underlying problem) or do they address different problems (meaning it might be possible to have to use both atomic operations and immutable types to design a fully concurrency-safe system)?

They are certainly not "substitutes".  I would say that atomicity addresses a specific problem with concurrent systems but immutability is more of a "nice-to-have".

If you are locking between concurrent threads then you will need atomic operations to do (for example) test-and-set and unlock-and-wait operations which are required to share data and do signaling.  There probably are other ways to accomplish this without atomicity but it probably gets a lot harder.

Immutable types are a hallmark of a concurrent/parallel architectures because threads can share data safely without worrying about modification.  Immutability also helps with data visibility optimizations.  But that said, immutability is not a requirement.

> I.e. atomic operations leads to a designing a system of atomically shared state while immutable types leads to designing a system that avoids sharing all-together?

Not really.  Atomicity is about avoiding race conditions when threads are updating the same state as mentioned above however sharing of state isn't necessarily atomic.

You can certainly share data between 2 threads without either atomicity *nor* immutable types.  Thread #1 updating `State1` which is shared by all threads and thread #2 updating `State2` which is also shared.

Comment: Why do you think so many people argue that functional languages (with immutable types like Clojure and Haskell) are somehow better for concurrency than other languages with good atomic library support like Java and c/c++?  Wouldn't a good atomic library remove all the potential problems in concurrent programming?

Comment: Language arguments are religious in nature @annoying_squid.  Certainly immutability makes things "better" and more optimal in many concurrent situations.  But it's more about good programming patterns than requirements around concurrency.